# Is the video card pulling memeory from my RAM?

Tags: windows-7, laptop, memory, graphics-card

I have a HP laptop (http://www.amazon.com/HP-Pavilion-dv6-7010us-15-6-Inch-Laptop/)
The  video card spec is "up to 3060MB total graphics memory", what does this really means? 
Where and what memory is the video card using?

MEMORY • 6GB DDR3 SDRAM (2 DIMM)

VIDEO GRAPHICS • AMD Radeon™ HD 7640G Discrete-Class graphics and up to 3060MB total
graphics memory(6)

Comment: A video **card** is unlikely to use system memory. I can only think of a single card which did that (i740 era, AGP). A graphics chip or APU on the other hand could very well do that. Especially if it is on the motherboard, on the chipset or in the CPU.

Answer (score 4):

You are absolutely right, these A-series are new APU from amd, these graphics are on single chip with CPU and are using shared memory, so yes it is using standard RAM.

Comment: Agreed.  Not sure about these newer chips, but when I have had "shared memory" cards before, you could usually adjust the amount that was allocated to the video card either in the BIOS or with an application that came with the card.

Comment: @techturtle: On pretty much every modern system, it adjusts automatically based on need.